# wp_dropdown_categories() でサブカテゴリの前に横棒を入れたい。

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Wordpressで`<?php wp_dropdown_categories(); ?>`でカテゴリの選択画面を表示させた時に、サブカテゴリの前には「-」のような棒を表示して親カテゴリと分けたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

引数でどうにかするのも難しそうなので置換でやってみたものの少しアレ。

```
function h_dopdown_cat() {
    echo preg_replace_callback( '/(<option[^>]*>)((?:&nbsp;)+)/u', function ( $matches ) {
        return $matches[1] . str_repeat( '–', strlen( $matches[2] ) / 18 ) . ' ';
    }, wp_dropdown_categories( [
        'echo'         => 0,
        'depth'        => 3,
        'hierarchical' => true
    ] ) );
}
```

と思ったところ、 Walkerクラスを自前で用意すればなんとかなりそうとのこと。
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/#comment-1823

```
class My_Walker_CategoryDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown {
    public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $pad = str_repeat( '-', $depth );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $category->name, $category );

        if ( isset( $args['value_field'] ) && isset( $category->{$args['value_field']} ) ) {
            $value_field = $args['value_field'];
        } else {
            $value_field = 'term_id';
        }

        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"" . esc_attr( $category->{$value_field} ) . "\"";

        // Type-juggling causes false matches, so we force everything to a string.
        if ( (string) $category->{$value_field} === (string) $args['selected'] ) {
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        }
        $output .= '>';
        $output .= $pad . $cat_name;
        if ( $args['show_count'] ) {
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;(' . number_format_i18n( $category->count ) . ')';
        }
        $output .= "</option>\n";
    }

}

wp_dropdown_categories( [
    'depth'        => 3,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'walker'       => new My_Walker_CategoryDropdown(),
] );
```

[image: 例]

Comment: 本当にありがとうございました。無事スクリーンショットのように表示できました。